# Tkinter does not update variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize if this is a redundant post, but I have spent a few hours sniffing out solutions around StackOverflow and other sources, this is where I ended up. AFAIK it should work.

Put simply, I can't fathom why my variable doesn't update more than once. When I run this program, it starts at '0.0' and updates to a realistic value (after time.sleep(5)), but only *once*. Theoretically it should update in real-time...

I realize you can't recreate my dev environment with my exact Modbus slave device, etc etc, but `flow_unpack` is a "good" variable because it prints to the Tkinter window once. If it was bad, it would return a ValueError or something. The problem is: why isn't it updating?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import minimalmodbus
import serial
import struct

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))

i = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 1)
i.serial.baudrate = 9600
i.serial.bytesize = 8
i.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_ODD
i.serial.stopbits = 1
i.serial.timeout = 1
i.debug = False

var = tk.DoubleVar()

label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()

mass_flow_rate = i.read_registers(registeraddress=246, numberOfRegisters=2,
    functioncode=3)
flow_ = [mass_flow_rate[0], mass_flow_rate[1]]
flow_pack = struct.pack('HH', flow_[0], flow_[1])
flow_unpack = round(struct.unpack('f', flow_pack)[0], 4)


def function():
    global flow_unpack
    var.set(flow_unpack)
    root.update()
    time.sleep(5)


root.after(2000, function)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You mean `var`? Why do you expect it to update more than once?

Comment: `var` is set to `flow_unpack` with `.set( )` so as far as I'm concerned they're the same. And it should update more than once due to the update function and the calling of said function with `root.after(time, function)`.

Comment: [`root.after(time, function)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) causes `function` to be called **once** after [time] ms.

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your code

```
def function():
    global flow_unpack
    var.set(flow_unpack)
    root.after(2000, function) # just add this for further calls
    # root.update() -> not needed, see Brian comment.
    # time.sleep(5) -> do you really need this? 
    # you will block the tkinter mainloop and your UI.
```

Comment: There is no need to call `root.update` when using `after` in this way. `root.update()` is implicitly called in the time between the return of this function and the next time the function is run.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley , I have commented it out